# Compute large powers a^m mod p; p prime

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Please advise on a short cut on how to solve $$7^{3216645} \pmod {17}$$ by hand.

So far I thought of using method of squaring and fast exponentiation (converting to binary form...) but these methods seem to be long.

Thank you!

Comment: Just use Fermat.  $7^{16}\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$.

Comment: and it's easy to see the exponent is 5 mod 16 @lulu

Comment: You can actually turn the exponent into a work around using mod 17, but it's a bit of a pain..

Comment: in this case, you can use $$3216645=17\cdot 189214+7$$$$189214=17\cdot 11130+4$$$$11130=17\cdot 654+12$$$$654=17\cdot 38+8$$$$38=17\cdot 2+4$$  with a bit  more of theory, to conclude it's congruent to $7^{37}$ which by the same logic is congruent to $7^5$